# spread operator breaks default property assignment in function definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

see https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagAoCdZ0BnUAXlAG9FRQBjaAQyKIDkGBbTAfgC5QjkeAJYA7AOYAaanQAWmWgGtMAE16gARrFjRMDEVJoBtAcPEBdPidGTEAXwDciRLVgiBoAMJzFmgB5lQAAoqGnomVg5scgByX2iDWXklZQDIBmgiTASAOlz0AmIpWz58QiIASjIAPkppFzdtTGy4MUDovEwRZUw8RJ9YOPLHW0QgA

```
// @flow
type Props = {
  className?: string,
  checked?: boolean,
  [string]: string,
};

const Checkbox = ({
  className = 'x',
  checked = false,
  ...props,
}: Props) => {
  console.log('render checkbox');
}
```

produces the errors:

```
9:   className = 'x',
               ^ Unexpected token =
10:   checked = false,
              ^ Unexpected token =
12: }: Props) => {
              ^ Unexpected token =>
```

this is valid javascript but is rejected by flow.  removing the `...props` removes the error, but I need this functionality.  Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a type-o. Extra comma

```
// @flow
type Props = {
  className?: string,
  checked?: boolean,
  [string]: string,
};

const Checkbox = ({
  className = 'x',
  checked = false,
  ...props
}: Props) => {
  console.log('render checkbox');
}
```

https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagAoCdZ0BnUAXlAG9FRQBjaAQyKIDkGBbTAfgC5QjkeAJYA7AOYAaanQAWmWgGtMAE16gARrFjRMDEVJoBtAcPEBdPidGTEAXwDciRLVgiBoAMJzFmgB5lQAAoqGnomVg5scgByX2iDWXklZQDIBmgiTASAOlz0AmI7PnxCIgBKMgA+SmkXN21MbLgxQOi8TBFlTDxEn1g4ssdbRCA

Also, you should define you indexer at the top of your type like this:

```
// @flow
type Props = {
  [string]: string,
  className?: string,
  checked?: boolean
};
```

Comment: thank you, I'm guessing the indexer need to be at the top so that it doesn't overwrite the explicit operators?

Comment: @JD. The indexer is at the top because flow will make the best guess based on the first attribute, and moving to the top just helps Flow get this right. I am sure there are use cases where you wouldn't want to, this is more of a code style tip than a rule. Even the Flow docs don't always do this. If there is a clear reason *not* to have the indexer at the top, I don't know what it is, and I'd be very interested in learning.